# if variable ain't null print it: null i'm confused

Tags: javascript

```
if (authorID) {
    console.log(authorID);
    $.ajax({
    -ajax stuff-
    )}
} else window.location.href="notLoggedIn.html";
```

ok this is my problem: in console `authorID` (a String) *does* get printed and it's printed as `null`.
My question is: why does this happen? Since authorID is null shouldn't be the else block the one executed?

I'm really new to Javascript/jQuery so I think i may just have missed some obvious thing, but wasn't able to figure it myself.

**edit:** here's how authorID is created:

```
if (session.getAttribute("authorID")!= null) {
    authorID = session.getAttribute("authorID").toString();
}
```

since i'm testing without logging in i'm expecting session.getAttribute() to return null

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle or give us a testable code ? If authorId **is** `null`, then it doesn't pass the `if` test.

Comment: are you sure it's not the string "null"? How is `authorID` created?

Comment: You don't have an `else` block.

Comment: where is authorID declared and initiated?  Also, please note you don't have an `else` block. everything else is executed anyway. You can also test `if (authorID == null)`

Comment: To follow on what @Cfreak commented, try `console.log(typeof authorID)`. That will tell you if `authorID` is indeed a string.

Comment: @imulsion SO is no place for such rude comments. Not everybody has english as native language...

Comment: @Cfreak & user1555863 I did as you suggested and typeof authorID logs String, here's how it is created:

if (session.getAttribute("authorID")!= null) {
authorID = session.getAttribute("authorID").toString();
}

i tried to change the if condition to check also if authorID is not the string "null", but still gets in the block as if the condition was true :/

imulsion: and I think i'm fine with that lol

Comment: can you add this code snippet as an edit to your question so it's more readable?

Comment: sure, i'm having troubles formatting the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, JavaScript is a very flexible language. It is very easy to get confused by "truthy" values.

null and false belong to those *truthy* common mistakes.

Somewhere *before* your method execution, a null value was converted into string. Maybe if you get the value from the DOM.

That's why on debug, you see "null" being written to the output. But in reality you have "null" as a string not the raw value of null.

for JavaScript this is evaluates to true:

```
if("null"){

}
```

The only way to eliminate this is to make a check of the datatype using typeof and check against the correct value.

```
if(a !== null && a !== "null"){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem is that a string always evaluates as true.  You have said `authorID` is a string; therefore `if (authorID)` will always evaluate true.

What you can do is test if your 'authorID' string does not equal 'null':

```
if (authorID !== 'null')
```

I imagine you want the page redirection to happen only when 'authorId' equals the string 'null, so your code would look like this:

```
if (authorID !== 'null') {
    console.log(authorID);
    $.ajax({
    // -ajax stuff-
    )}
} else {
    window.location.href = "notLoggedIn.html";
}
```

*Alternatively*, now that you've edited the question to show how 'authorID' is defined:

Change that block to:

```
if (session.getAttribute("authorID")) {
    authorID = session.getAttribute("authorID").toString();
} else {
    authorID = null;
}
```

*Then* you can use your original conditional:

```
if (authorID) {
    console.log(authorID);
    $.ajax({
    // -ajax stuff-
    )}
} else {
    window.location.href = "notLoggedIn.html";
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the solution in your third code block but still had the problem, probably i transformed authorID into string later..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a read of: http://saladwithsteve.com/2008/02/javascript-undefined-vs-null.html

In your case, the end of that article shows the mistake you've made:

```
if (foo == null) {
       foo = "Joe";
    }
```

Is equal to:

```
if (!foo) {
       foo = "Joe";
    }
```

I did a quick jsfiddle that I hope will spell it out better for you: http://jsfiddle.net/vp9Fa/1/

Comment: I didn't even know of jsfiddle, thanks! The article clarified things a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

to pass the if condition authorID should be initialized as a boolean variable.

```
var authorID=true;

if (authorID)
{
  //code if true
}
else
{
 //code if false
}
```

in your code you can do like below

```
if (authorID!=null)
{
 //code if not null
}
else
{
 //code if null
}
```